# Illegal Continue: Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, continue

I have a two for loops checking two sets of items. I have the following code:

```
for(var key in powder){
    for(var key2 in powder){
        if(key == key2){ continue; };
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

([...]s are unimportant info.)

But, javascript gives me an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement`

And I cannot figure out why! I have checked multiple resources(W3Schools, stackoverflow, ect.) and it did not have anything. Please help!

Comment: And what do you want to continue with here ?

Comment: @adneo With the 2nd for loop

Comment: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea/500531#500531)

Comment: can't reproduce -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bj45eebr/**

Comment: @Pilot What's a fiddle? Are you joking?

Comment: This should work fine. Are you sure you're not using a closure instead of a for... in loop? In that case, you'd need to use `return` instead of continue.

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla: Pilot was referring to jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). You can also use the snippet editor when writing posts here on Stack Overflow. Either way, it can be helpful to offer a [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the provided snippet. Maybe you have another `continue`. I'll downvote unless you give more information.

Comment: @adeneo http://jsfiddle.net/bj45eebr/1/

Comment: You call it in a function. That's reason. There is no loop in the function. That's different scope.

Comment: @Han Then what do I use?

Comment: you should be using a `return` statement instead of continue in your `update` function, if you want to exit the function.

Comment: In this case you can use `return;` but it's better that you tweak the function so that it will `return false;` to break and `return true;` in case not break. And when you call `update` function in you loop you can use: `if (!update(...)){continue;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried similar code in js and works fine. May be some problem with lines of code which you didn't post or some problem with your powder variable

```
<html>

<script>

 function fun(){
    var powder =[1,2,4,5];
   for(var key in powder){
     for(var key2 in powder){
     if(key == key2){ alert("con");continue; };
    }
}

}
  </script>

     <body onload="fun()"></body>
 </html>
```

The following code will result in illegal continue statement.The continue statement must be present in the loop not in the called function.

```
 <html>

 <script>
      function funOne(){
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  fun();
 }
  }
   function fun(){
    if(1==1){ //this line is the cause of error
     continue;
   }
   var powder =[1,2,4,5];
    for(var key in powder){
     for(var key2 in powder){
     if(key == key2){ alert("con");continue; };
   }
}

}
  </script>

   <body onload="funOne()"></body>
 </html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bj45eebr/1/ <-- There's the full thing. Check the console after running it.